# Iterate through class properties using an action?

Tags: c#, linq, reflection, csvhelper

I'm using `CsvHelper` to import `csv` files, and in order to do so I use a mapping class as follows:

```
private class MyClassMap : ClassMap<MyClass>
{
    public MyClassMap ()
    {
        Map(m => m.Number).Name("Number");
        Map(m => m.Name).Name("Name");
    }
}
```

Most classes contain many more properties. So what I first did is create an `Attribute` class and added the attribute to all public properties. So I can change the mapping code:

```
private class MyClassMap : ClassMap<MyClass>
{
    public MyClassMap ()
    {
        var properties = typeof(MyClass).GetProperties();
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var attr = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(HeaderAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault();
            if (attr != null)
            {
               //Here what?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I will make the above ctor code an extension method.

How would I use the `Map()` method in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `HeaderAttribute` accepts a `Header` as a parameter and exposes it over `Header` property :

```
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        var attr = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(HeaderAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault() as HeaderAttribute;
        if (attr != null)
        {
           //Here we use the Map method overload that takes a Type and a MemberInfo

            this.Map(typeof(MyClass), property).Name(attr.Header);
        }
    }
```